# Loading JAXB objects to Apache Hive/Impala

Tags: serialization, hadoop, hive, hdfs, impala

Consider a complex java (JAXB) object with multiple primitives and collections as member variables.  The Reducer phase emits such objects into HDFS as a < K, V > pair, where K is an id and V, the object's serialized form (SequenceFileOutputFormat).
is it possible to load these java serialized objects from HDFS/local location to Hive/Impala?

MongoDB has the ability to store JAXB objects as a json document out-of-box.  Any help to achieve the same on Hive or Impala is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, use sequence files.

This link should help: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/

The SerDe interface allows you to instruct Hive as to how a record should be processed. A SerDe is a combination of a Serializer and a Deserializer (hence, Ser-De). The Deserializer interface takes a string or binary representation of a record, and translates it into a Java object that Hive can manipulate. The Serializer, however, will take a Java object that Hive has been working with, and turn it into something that Hive can write to HDFS or another supported system. Commonly, Deserializers are used at query time to execute SELECT statements, and Serializers are used when writing data, such as through an INSERT-SELECT statement.

Thanks